# List of proofs of Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: analysis

I am looking for different proofs of the theorem :

If $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$ and if any $\epsilon>0$ is given, then there exists a polynomial $p$ on $[a,b]$ such that

$|f(x)-P(x)|< \epsilon $
for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite proof uses probability! Here are two exercises that will help you prove it.

> Step 1: Let $Z_n$ be a sequence of random variables and $c$ a constant such that for each $\epsilon > 0$ it holds
>   that $$\mathbb{P}[|Z_n −c| > \epsilon]  \rightarrow 0, \ \  \text{as } n \rightarrow 0.$$ Show that for any bounded continuous function $g,$
>   $$\mathbb{E}[g(Z_n)] \rightarrow g(c) \ \  \text{as } n \rightarrow 0.$$

A hint for Step $1$ is to use the fact that $g$ is bounded and the definition of continuity.

> Step 2: Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $[0,1]$. Consider the $\textit{Bernstein Polynomials,}$ defined by
>   $$ B_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f \left( \frac{k}n \right) \dbinom{n}k x^k (1-x)^{n-k}. $$ 
>   Show that $B_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly.

A hint for Step $2$ is to use the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: I have seen the proof which uses only Bernstein Polynomials .
I am looking for a proof that uses Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial .
Thanks for your post , I will try to prove it.